# Using Materialize.min.css for cards but can't size them to fixed and can't show them in a single row

Tags: html, css

Using [Materialize.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css) for creating material cards

Can't align **multiple cards in a signle row** (side by side)

Another problem I'm facing is that I can't make the **cards of fixed size**. Resizing the browser window makes them unusable at some point.

[Reference Screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/Hh7tmxO)

```
My Code: https://pastebin.com/uu2YgdGK
```

Try on [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/lubogej/1)

Comment: post your scriptcode as text and not as image.

Comment: Can you post your code as a Fiddle, so we can run it and help you fix it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although your question looks valid at first sight it does not meet SO [minimal site criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please modify question accordingly to [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so we both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: See also [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Post your code as code and not as links!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bro Use this code to fix

- Use materialize css classes and use media query to set site
  responsive.
- Use m12 on main div instead of m2
- Use m2 class on card div
- Final check code and Run Snippet

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" />
        <style>
            .card-image {
                max-height: 100% !important;
            }
            .card.small {
                height: auto !important;
            }
            @media(max-width: 1199px) {
                .card {
                    width: 20% !important;
                }
            }
            @media(max-width: 1024px) {
                .card {
                    width: 33.33% !important;
                }
            }
            @media(max-width: 625px) {
                .card {
                width: 50% !important;
                }
            }
            @media(max-width: 414px) {
                .card {
                width: 100% !important;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
</html>
<body>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m12">
            <!--<div class='md-padding' layout="row" layout-wrap>-->
                <!--<div class="container">-->
                    <div class="card small col m2">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                            <img class="activator" src="https://fbdev.mpsecure.com/groupon/201301_dir/images/upload/1363923993_tmplogo_wolf_1.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Bharatiya Janta party
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit" name="vote1">VOTE</button>
                            </span>
                            <!--<p><a href="#">This is a link</a></p>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card small col m2">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                            <img class="activator" src="https://fbdev.mpsecure.com/groupon/201301_dir/images/upload/1363923993_tmplogo_wolf_1.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Bharatiya Janta party
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit" name="vote1">VOTE</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card small col m2">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                            <img class="activator" src="https://fbdev.mpsecure.com/groupon/201301_dir/images/upload/1363923993_tmplogo_wolf_1.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Bharatiya Janta party
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit" name="vote1">VOTE</button>
                            </span>
                            <!--<p><a href="#">This is a link</a></p>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card small col m2">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                            <img class="activator" src="https://fbdev.mpsecure.com/groupon/201301_dir/images/upload/1363923993_tmplogo_wolf_1.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Bharatiya Janta party
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit" name="vote1">VOTE</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card small col m2">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                            <img class="activator" src="https://fbdev.mpsecure.com/groupon/201301_dir/images/upload/1363923993_tmplogo_wolf_1.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Bharatiya Janta party
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit" name="vote1">VOTE</button>
                            </span>
                            <!--<p><a href="#">This is a link</a></p>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card small col m2">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                            <img class="activator" src="https://fbdev.mpsecure.com/groupon/201301_dir/images/upload/1363923993_tmplogo_wolf_1.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Bharatiya Janta party
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit" name="vote1">VOTE</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!--</div>-->
            <!--</div>-->
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the above code. It worked like a charm. But what if I want the cards to be of fixed aspect ratio? I don't want them to change the aspect ratio according to the window

Comment: Set fixed width and height for cards it'll not change the aspect ratio for every device

Comment: I have used media query so its changing the width and height of the cards according to device if you don't want just remove it